# Sum function in For loop with column changing

Tags: vba

I am not completely new to coding, but I am rather new to VBA. I just finished a form, but in it I have this big ugly chunk of code that I can not seem to cut down with a for loop.

```
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "C").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!Q" & firstRow & ":Q" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "D").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!R" & firstRow & ":R" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "E").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!S" & firstRow & ":S" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "F").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!T" & firstRow & ":T" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "G").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!U" & firstRow & ":U" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "H").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!V" & firstRow & ":V" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "I").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!W" & firstRow & ":W" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "J").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!X" & firstRow & ":X" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "K").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!Y" & firstRow & ":Y" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "L").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!Z" & firstRow & ":Z" & lastRow & ")"
Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, "M").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!AA" & firstRow & ":AA" & lastRow & ")"
```

The problem is that the column number changes, and I do not get a For working with letters, OR I do not get the column index set with a number, OR I do get those two working, but without using a SUM function. I am just interested in seeing how I could have written this code better.

I was thinking along the line of the following

```
b = 3
For a = 17 To 27
    Sheets("Factory").Cells(4, b).Formula = "=SUM(Orders!" & a & firstRow & ":" & a & lastRow & ")"
    b = b + 1
Next a
```

Regards

Comment: run this in the immediate window, and check the resulting formulas in the cells .... `Sheets("Factory").range("c4:m4").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!Q1:Q40)"`

Comment: Unfortunately the suggestion does not fully work due to the fact that as soon as I try and use the code with variables (seeing that the # rows change every day) I can not get it to work. But thanks for the immediate window tip, it is something that I did not use before.

Comment: it was not meant as an answer. it was meant to show you that a single command can fill the range with correct formulas, instead of using 11 commands

Comment: @jsotola's example should work similarly to mine: `Sheets("Factory").Range("C4:M4").Formula = "=SUM(Orders!Q" & firstRow & ":Q" & lastRow & ")"`

Comment: Oh ok, sorry I did not pick up on that earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Factory!C4:M4] = "=SUM(Orders!Q" & firstRow & ":Q" & lastRow & ")"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-evaluate-method-excel

Communication between VBA and Excel is relatively slow, so accessing range is faster than cell by cell https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/

Comment: Very nice Slai, this worked very well indeed, and a nice way of approaching the problem. Answered the question with even less code. Will use it in other places as well that did work with a FOR loop, but that I can do with even less code.  :)